# Can VisualStudio 2015 be installed on Windows Vista?

Tags: visual-studio

On my Vista machine, while installing VS 2015 CE, the installer shows message "the specified program requires new version of windows".

Is there anything special we have to do to install VS 2015 CE or it does not support Vista?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 **can not** be installed on Vista.

Supported Windows versions for Visual Studio 2015

- Windows 10
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 8
- Windows 7 Service Pack 1
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

[Reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs#1).

Comment: Thank you Rashwan, however, how do I resolve the issue "The specific program requires newer version of Windows"?

Comment: @TechTurtle, I must have read the Microsoft wrongly. I have updated my answer and Visual Studio 2015 cannot be installed on Windows Vista. Sorry for the misunderstanding.